# How can I use the client-side validation of a RequiredFieldValidator in combination with my custom usercontrol?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, validation

Using the `ValidationProperty` I've managed to connect a `RequiredFieldValidator` with my custom control. When I enable client script in the validator, JavaScript errors occur.

Is there a way to tell the `RequiredFieldValidator` how it can validate my custom control in the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first instance ensure the ControlToValidate property is pointing at the control you wish to validate.

Worryingly the JavaScript error is a bit weird as using RequiredFieldValidator would emit the stock ASP.NET validation code.

You could used a **Custom Validator** where you define the JavaScript method you want to execute to perform the validation.

Comment: I consider this a valid solution too, so +1 from me.

I've actually solved this issue by letting the custom JavaScript control generate an hidden field which the validators can connect to. As much as that is a workaround, it also allows all standard validators to work.